# Selecting data in XSL from different sections of XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT.

I have an XML-

```
<root>
  <fiberList>
              <fiber>
                     <A>abcd</A>
                     <B>bcde</B>
                     <C>cdef</C>

              </fiber>
    </fiberList>
           <generatorList>
              <generator>
                     <D>defg</D>
                     <E>efgh</E>
              </generator>
 </root>
```

I want to transform this XML into another XML through XSL.
The resulting XML should be something like this-

```
<parent>
          <child>
                  <M>abcd</M>
                  <N>bcde</N>
                  <O>efgh</O>
          </child>
</parent>
```

But I am getting the following XML after transformation-

```
<parent>
          <child>
                  <M>abcd</M>
                  <N>bcde</N>
                  <O/>
          </child>
</parent>
```

My XSL is the following-

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:element name="parent">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="root/fiberList/fiber"/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="root/fiberList/fiber">
    <xsl:element name="child">
        <xsl:element name="M">
            <xsl:value-of select="A"/>
        </element>
        <xsl:element name="N">
            <xsl:value-of select="B"/>
        </element>
       <xsl:element name="O">
           <xsl:value-of select="root/generatorList/generator/E"/>
       </element>
   </element>
</template>
</stylesheet>
```

Please help.

Comment: What is the version of XSLT you are using? And please correct the samples to be valid XMLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i haven't tried it .. but i think
a leading '/' is missing here :

```
 <xsl:value-of select="root/generatorList/generator/E"/>
```

try this please :

```
 <xsl:value-of select="/root/generatorList/generator/E"/>
```

otherwise the xslt engine is trying to find a relative path
*"root/generatorList/generator/E*" starting at the matched
element (/root/fiberList/fiber) of the template but there is no
*/root/fiberList/fiber/root/generatorList/generator/E*.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate, you could use this stylesheet too:

**XSLT-1.0**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <parent>
            <child>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="fiberList/fiber/A | fiberList/fiber/B | generatorList/generator/E"/>
            </child>
        </parent>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="A">
        <M>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </M>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="B">
        <N>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </N>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="E">
        <O>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </O>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**EDIT:**

In **XSLT-2.0** you can simplify the `xsl:apply-templates` instruction to the following:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="fiberList/fiber/(A | B) | generatorList/generator/E"/>
```